# airflow metabase the column end_date in table dag_run is null

Tags: instance, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, metabase

ENV: 1.8.2

airflow metabase 
   table:  dag_run
   column: end_date
       99% value of  column end_date :   is null
       1%  value of  column end_date :   is not null

Q:
why? is there any idea/setting to fix this situation?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are only two spots in the code that set the dag run end date. When a dag run [hits the timeout](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/1.8.2/airflow/jobs.py) and when you [set a dag run to failed/success in the UI](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/1.8.2/airflow/www/views.py#L2319).

If you want to fix this, I'd look into the [update_state](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/1.8.2/airflow/models.py#L4242-L4258) method of the DagRun class and set the end date if the run is being set to a terminating state. Of course you should submit a PR to github with your change!